# Copying code from current file to another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to copy several lines of code from one python file to another.

The idea here is that I'm setting up a simple character creator for a text-based adventure game and I need to transfer the code over to a charcter sheet to use later on in the project.

I've tried using the .write function, but it doesn't accept integers

edit;Grammar

edit2;messed up in the 'else' bit

```
import sys
C_sheet=open("CharacterSheet.txt", 'w')

strength=10
dexterity=10
cunning=10
magic=10

mana=200
health_points=100

name=input("Name your character; ",)
C_sheet.write(name)


invalid2=True

def job():
    role=input("Choose your role: Fighter(F), Mage(M), Thief(T): ", )
    role=role.upper()

    if role=="F":
        st=(strength+5)
        dex=(dexterity+0)
        cun=(cunning-3)
        mag=(magic-5)
        mn=(mana-50)
        hp=(health_points+25)
        C_sheet.write("Fighter")
        C_sheet.write(st)
        C_sheet.write(dex)
        C_sheet.write(cun)
        C_sheet.write(mag)
        C_sheet.write(mn)
        C_sheet.write(hp)
        C_sheet.close()
        invalid2=False


    else:
        print("invalid")
        invalid2=True

while invalid2:
    job()
```

I'm trying to get the other file to look something like this

```
name=("placeholder")

st=15
dex=10
cun=7
mag=5
mn=150
hp=225
```

Comment: `.read()` gives a `str` value unless the file is opened to `bytes` where it will give `bytes`

Comment: Also please clean up your code.

Comment: which parts should I clean up?

Comment: @EricJin not only is that comment not helpful to new users, I would argue it's pretty condescending

Comment: @bootsocks you're correct, `file.write` does only take strings for files opened in `w` or `wt` mode. You can use string formatting or for python3.5+ [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look through that

Comment: You should just be able to convert the int to string as follows: `C_sheet.write(dex)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `fh.write` only takes strings for files opened in `w` or `wt` mode. To get around this, you can use:

## string formatting

```py
with open('somefile.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write('%d' % 5) # for ints
    fh.write('%f' % 6) # for floats
    fh.write('%s' % 'string') # for strings

# OR str.format syntax 
with open('somefile.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write('{}'.format(5)) # transferrable to all types of variables
```

## f-strings (python 3.5+ only)

```py
with open('somefile.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(f'{5}') # will work for all variables
```

f-strings would be my vote, as it works the same for all variables, though string-formatting with `{}` and `%` is portable for python3 and python2, if that's an issue.

To get the format you are looking for with both options:

## string format

```py
with open('somefile.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write('dex = %d' % dexterity)
    # will write "dex = 10" or whatever you have substituted
```

## f-string

```py
with open('somefile.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(f'dex = {dexterity})
```

Comment: string formatting also refers to `"{}".format('foo')`